# Bash using first lines counted output to add whitespace to following lines

Tags: bash, printf

I have this code here

```
printf '$request1 = "select * from whatever where this = that and active = 1 order by something asc";\n' 
| perl -pe 's/select/SELECT/gi ; s/from/\n   FROM/gi ; s/where/\n      WHERE/gi ; s/and/\n      AND/gi ; s/order by/\n         ORDER BY/gi ; s/asc/ASC/gi ; s/desc/DESC/gi ;' 
| awk '{gsub(/\r/,"");printf "%s\n%d",$0,length($0)}'
```

it produce output like this currently

```
$request1 = "SELECT * 
22   FROM whatever 
17      WHERE this = that 
24      AND active = 1 
21         ORDER BY something ASC";
```

I would like to take the count of the first line (22) and add that amount of whitespace to each additional line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you don't want to print the numbers, change your AWK command to:

```
awk 'NR == 1 {pad = length($0); print} NR > 1 {gsub(/\r/,""); printf "%*s%s\n", pad, " ", $0}'
```

Output:

```
$request1 = "SELECT * 
                         FROM whatever 
                            WHERE this = that 
                            AND active = 1 
                               ORDER BY something ASC";
```

Comment: Could you get it to stop counting after the equal sign?

Comment: @ehime: If you mean that you want the subsequent lines to be aligned with the equal sign, then change `length($0)` to `index($0, "=") + offset` where `offset` is some value to use to move everything to the right or left a little bit depending on where you want the alignment relative to the equal sign.

Comment: By the way, all the mixed piped code in your question could be collapsed into one Bash, Perl or AWK script.

Comment: I agree, this is just testing stuff via the command line atm ;)